# Does useCallback hook create a function everytime a component renders in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

During the job interview, I was asked how to optimize a component in React.

So I answered with an example of using **useCallback** and **useMemo** hooks.

Because whenever a components re-renders, functions and variables declared inside of the component are newly created which results in those newly created values occupying memory space.

However, with a help of those two hooks, it is possible to save memory because using **useCallback** and **useMemo** prevents creating the function and variable again and again by saving and reusing the previous result, as long as a state inside the dependency array is not changed during the component re-rendering.

So far, this was my answer. But the interviewer said **useCallback** does not prevent creating a function. Even if **useCallback** is used, a function is still created.

I do not get this part. How is the function created again inside the useCallback hook?

Is there something I'm missing about **useCallback** and **useMemo**?

Comment: See my explanation below, please ask if you are not clear at any points. I will try to make that more understandable from your feedbacks.

Comment: @RyanLe Thank you for the detail explanation with the example below. What I understand from Khalt's comment is that even using useCallback hook, a function is still re-created however it does not re-create a new reference in the memory. Instead the function is re-assigned to the same reference before?

Comment: Functions are objects, and every newly created object are different in term of memory allocation. With useCallback. Functions are not re-created but the variable (changeWithUseCallback) that reference to useCallback in the function does. Which also mean that the function inside useCallback is always the same in every renders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Here I made an example so you can see `useCallback` in action:**

In the example bellow: `useCallback` will prevent newly `changeWithUseCallback` re-create every new render, result that `Child1` never gets re-render because it's props (changeWithUseCallback) never re-created.

Otherwise, in the `Child2` component, its prop (changeWithoutUseCallback) is always re-created during renders, so the component itself will re-render.

**Please note that [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) will skip rendering the component if its props have not changed**

So I would say that you are right about `useCallback` that it will keep the function/variable reference during renders, or `prevent creating new function/variable` during renders.

```js
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  const changeWithUseCallback = React.useCallback(() => {
    console.log("onChangeChild");
  }, []);
  const changeWithoutUseCallback = () => {
    console.log("onChangeChild");
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setValue(value + 1)}>
        Change value
      </button>
      <h1>{value}</h1>
      <Child1 onChange={changeWithUseCallback} />
      <Child2 onChange={changeWithoutUseCallback} />
    </div>
  );
}

const Child1 = React.memo(({ onChange }) => {
  console.log("Child1 render!!!");
  return null;
});

const Child2 = React.memo(({ onChange }) => {
  console.log("Child2 render!!!");
  return null;
});

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: From my understanding, the function/variable is still re-created. After all, the entire component gets rerendered/re-exectued -> the variables are declared and set every single time. The only difference is that they end up referencing the same place in memory.

Comment: Reassign could be a better word in this case since recreate means having a new reference.

Answer (score 1):

It does recreate the function. But, it uses the reference to the function that's created earlier, given no dependency is changed. So, that might prevent re-rendering of child component or triggering another hook that has the function in its dependency array.